# Remove location updates immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fusedlocation

Im using fused location API And i have 2 intent services:

The first intent service is registering GoogleApiClient Object.
The second intent service is getting location updates frequently and does not using GoogleApiClient Object.

I want to call : `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,pendingIntent);`

from the service that is getting location updates to stop getting location immediately but i cant becuase mGoogleApiClient does not registered ther.

Im confused about the solution to this ? Any ideas?

Comment: So register it there?

Comment: I thought about it but it's strange? cant we just register mGoogleApiClient in one service and use it in other services??

Comment: If your `mGoogleApiClient` is created in a different `IntentService`, you wouldn't be able to use it anyways as an `IntentService` is destroyed immediately upon finishing `onHandleIntent()` and therefore probably doesn't even exist when your second `IntentService` runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app can connect to `GoogleApiClient` in more than one place at the same time. It will be much easier on yourself to connect to a `GoogleApiClient` with [`blockingConnect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) in your activity recognition `IntentService` such that you can call `removeLocationUpdates()` directly when you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I tryied to use this.stopSelf(); and in the other intent service that is registered to GoogleApiClient i removed location updates and it looks like it's working . I'll update after i'll check it soon . But your answer is accepted.